# How to remove SEO Yoast page title filter?

Tags: wordpress

I have installed the wordpress SEO Yoast plugin on my blog. I want to avoid using SEO Yoast generated title for my blog. Is there any way I can remove filter that are being applied by SEO Yoast plugin for `wp_title()`?
 I want to use the page title as SEO title.

```
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'te_before_filter_wp_title' );
function te_before_filter_wp_title( $title ) {
    echo  $title;
    //exit;
    return $title;

}

add_filter( 'wp_title', 'te_after_filter_wp_title' ,9999);
function te_after_filter_wp_title( $title ) {
 echo  $title;
    //exit; 
 return $title;

}
```

I have write this code to test the title. And title in `te_before_filter_wp_title` and in `te_after_filter_wp_title` is different. So it is being modified by SEO YOAST plugin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With older versions of WPSEO (v1~2), you can remove [the filter it applies](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/wordpress-seo/tags/1.5.2.2/frontend/class-frontend.php#L57) with the following code:

```php
add_action('init', function() {
    global $wpseo_front;
    remove_filter('wp_title', array( $wpseo_front, 'title' ), 15 );
}, 20 );
```

With newer versions of WPSEO (~3+) and WordPress (4.4+), the filter(s) can be removed with the following code:

```php
add_action('init', function () {
    $wpseo_front = WPSEO_Frontend::get_instance();

    remove_filter('pre_get_document_title', array($wpseo_front, 'title' ), 15 );
    remove_filter('wp_title', array($wpseo_front, 'title'), 15 );
});
```